# split actionbar has different transparencies

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock and I have a split actionbar. The top actionbar has the transparency that I want. The problem is that the bottom action bar is completely transparent and I have no idea how to get them to look the same.

Here is my styles xml:

```
<resources>    
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />

    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/customActionBarDropdown</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/customActionBarDropdown</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#88000000</item>
        <item name="background">#88000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customActionBarDropdown" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
    </style>        
</resources>
```

Anyone know if there is another parameter that I need to include to give the bottom actionbar the same transparency?

Thanks

Comment: In Java, you call `setSplitBackgroundDrawable()` to set the background of the split action bar. Perhaps there is an `android:splitBackground` or something equivalent at the theme level.

Comment: You are right. Just found it. I used <item name="backgroundSplit">